# How throw error when export (SRS) Report to pdf file when subreport fail

Tags: reporting-services, srs

How throw error, avoiding export (SRS) Report to pdf file when subreport fail?

I try export Report to PDF file with API

I tried http://localhost/ReportServer?/MyReport&Param1=0201-AAA049&rs:Format=PDF
and
I tried http://localhost/ReportServer?/MyReport&Param1=0201-AAA049&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF

The file is export with inside message "Error: Subreport could not be shown". I need that call response something like http status code 500.